# What application has this icon in taskbar of Windows-10? [left hand pressing a key]

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, unwanted-application

*I'm not a windows user for years, but some my relatives are.*

I've been just pinged by them and asked to explain **the new icon** shown on their taskbar (because *"you are a computer guy"*, you know)...

- The icon: [image: This icon]
- The window: [image: blank window]

My investigation resulted in:

- It's in **taskbar**, not in notifications (i.e. closer to left).
- It disappears after reboot.
- It displays a small blank white window if clicked on.
- It looks like it does nothing.

My googling failed.

- Can anybody tell me what is this?
- How to get rid of it?

Yep, that are crops from sorta screenshots taken with a phone sent via WhatsApp...
Yep, that PC is running standard builtin windows antiviral tool...
Yep, it's a mere desktop PC, not a notebook, with normal non-touchscreen display.
And yes, this PC is not local to me and is operated by a non-tech person.

Comment: you may want to click on the icon to show the blank window, open up task manager to see it's process name, right click on the process choose show file location to see what file it correspond to.

Comment: If I'll have a chance to get close enough to that PC at the moment when the icon is on, I'll definitely do that.

Right now I still have a hope that this is something "system" and known to the rest of the world :)

Comment: Open [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), set the filter as "Operation contains process". Now when you open that icon, you may see that process name.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the icon for [PrintKey-Pro](http://www.warecentral.com/).

From the web site:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a some sort of a (damaged) *on-screen keyboard application* - the white rectangle is probably a (damaged) keyboard:

[image]

Try clicking on different parts of that rectangle whereas the focus is in the Notepad (or some other application waiting for the keyboard input).